# braintree how to vault a payment method ready for subscription

Tags: braintree

I'd like to create a customer with a payment method then store the payment method in the vault

and then to create a subscription for the user

so far I have this:

```
    $rs = \Braintree_Customer::create([
            'id'                 =>$m_id,
            'firstName'          =>$username,
            'paymentMethodNonce' =>$nonce
            ]);
```

but this doesn't appear to be storing payment methods in the vault, is the above code correct for storing payment methods in the vault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the `customer_id` and `paymentmethodnonce` to BT. Follow the ways

```
$result = Braintree_PaymentMethod::create([
    'customerId' => '12345',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => nonceFromTheClient
]);
```

From the result you can get the braintree token `(token = result.payment_method.token)` store in the database. You can use this token for the subscription.

Comment: Thank you this appears to have done it, I find it really hard to figure out the structure of response objects  so for the benefit of others : $result->paymentMethod->token is how you can retrieve the token